# Gráfico tiempo de ejecución

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Necesito crear un gráfico que compare dos funciones, y situe en el eje de las X las filas leidas
y en el eje de las Y el tiempo de ejecución.

De momento, he creado una función, para intentar extraer el gráfico de ésta primero.

El script que he realizado es el siguiente:

```
def get_column_pandas(path, column):
    pandas = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=';')
    columna = list(pandas.iloc[:, column])


get_column_pandas(path_artists, 2)
fin = default_timer()
print(fin - inicio)
```

Esto me devuelve una lista de los valores que tengo que mostrar en el eje x (variable columna) y el tiempo total de ejecución de la función.

Pero llegado a este punto no se como lo puedo graficar.

Tenéis alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes los datos para el eje X e Y en una lista (cada eje una lista distinta) solo tienes que ponerlos en la grafica:

```
plt.plot([datosEjeX], [datosEjeY])
plt.show()
```

Si quieres comparar, pon ambas graficas en una misma figra:

```
plt.plot([datosEjeX1], [datosEjeY1], format1, [datosEjeX2], [datosEjeY2], format2)
plt.show()
```

en el ejemplo de arriba, `format` es el estilo de cada grafica.

Si quieres grafica de barras utiliza `plt.bar` en vez de `plt.plot`